# Converting site to html5 and cross browser compatibility

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a site which is not compatible in IE6,IE7,IE8 and I want to use html5.

Should I first make it IE compatible then go for html5 or go for html5 then make it IE compatible?

Does converting to html5 will add trouble to make it IE compatible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Ian does html5 helps in browser compatibility ?

Answer (score 1):

The earlier versions won't recognise any of the new elements should you use them (which of course you don't have to).

But you can make these versions of IE recognise these elements by simply adding the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script.

As for the first question, if you want to use HTML5 then go ahead and perhaps make it IE compatible as you go along.